# Are there samples somewhere which use "iPhoneOSGameView"?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Recently I stumbled over "iPhoneOSGameView" which seems to be part of MonoTouch (or MONO?). It seems to be a base view for game development but I cannot find any samples on how to use it. Is there more to it, like animation helpers or sprites? Or is it only a OpenGL wrapper?

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in the MonoTouch samples here: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/monotouch-samples/blob/master/GLPaint-GV/GLPaint.cs

Comment: Thanks! I even had that on disk but missed it for some reason! :-)